# HttpServletResponse#sendError How to change ContentType

Tags: servlets, content-type, http-error

I'm creating a simple Servlet to answer a form submition. This servlet receive POST request and should response Application/JSON datas. This is working well.
I want now to add errors managment to my servlet: If the servlet receive bad request parameters, I want it to answer the client a 400 — "Bad Request" response with a simple `{"error":"ERROR MESSAGE"}` JSON response.

I'm using the `HttpServletResponse#sendError(int,String)` to correctly send the error but the `ContentType` of the response is always set to `text/html`, even though I used `HttpServletResponse#setContentType("application/json")` before.

Is this the good way to send error using Servets ? How can I force the `ContentType` of the response to `application/json`?

Sample code of the doPost() method of my test Servlet :

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("{\"error\":1}");
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That works [as specified](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError%28int,%20java.lang.String%29):

> Sends an error response to the client using the specified status and
>   clears the buffer. The server defaults to creating the response to
>   look like an HTML-formatted server error page containing the specified
>   message, setting the content type to "text/html".

```
HttpServletResponse.sendError(int)
```

on the other hand does not have this restriction/feature.

> Sends an error response to the client using the specified status code
>   and clearing the buffer.

This means: set the content type, write to the buffer, call `sendError(400)`.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply !
I tried what you explained. Not sure if doing well because it doesn't work as expected. :(
Not sure about the "write to the buffer" part. I edited the first post with a sample of code I am using for testing purpose.

Comment: This didn't work for me. sendError would ignore whatever I wrote before.

Comment: It doesn't work because the JavaDocs has this appended statement: **HttpServletResponse.sendError(int) is equivalent to calling HttpServletResponse.sendError(int, String) with the same status code and null for the message.**

Answer (score 33):

I recently had this issue when wanting to send error messages inside of a JAX-RS application. `sendError` would always return text/html, per the spec. I had to do the following, given a `HttpServletResponse response`:

```
response.resetBuffer();
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
response.getOutputStream().print("{\"errorMessage\":\"You can't use this!\"}");
response.flushBuffer(); // marks response as committed -- if we don't do this the request will go through normally!
```

The `flushBuffer` is critical to mark the response as committed, as `sendError` does. At first I tried just calling close on the output stream, but what would happen is my filter would run then the JAX-RS resource would continue to run normally, then I'd get the error message AND the normal response concatenated together with 200 status code!

`resetBuffer` is there just in case anything else has set headers or written some content before this filter.

Comment: Wonder, too, to what extent that specific behavior depends on the particular JavaEE platform.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling response.sendError(int), use response.setStatus(int).

Comment: This won't trigger error-page confing in JBoss/WildFly